# Rounded corners on linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linear layout with 2 text views that have different background colors. I want to make the whole view (linearlayout) with rounded corners. I tried enclosing it in MaterialCardview (as I was able to achieve that effect when I set the whole fragment layout inside) but for some reason it is not working. What do I need to do to achieve rounded corner on the view?

```
<android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/Transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tutTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/tutorial_title"
                android:text="Text 1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tutBody"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/tutorial_body"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:text="This is a hint"
                android:textColor="@color/main_dark_grey"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Note: I know some might suggest to use xml drawable with rounded background. This Won't work as the children background color will take over the transparency and will remain sharp edges

Comment: its good if you share your expected output as image

Comment: why you don't using shape drawable in both of linear and it's child layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make the whole view (linearlayout) with rounded corners.

Since the `LinearLayout` covers all the `CardView`, then the whole view, **is the CardView**. 
So instead of  setting transparent background to the `CardView`, set it to the `LinearLayout`, set a background color to the `CardView` and you will see rounded corners. 
If you set transparent color to both the `CardView` and the `LinearLayout` how do you expect to see rounded corners since **there are no corners**?

Comment: I am expecting the children (which are Textview with background colors) to have rounded corners where they intersect with cardview corners

Comment: If you supply 0 margins, the top TextView will have rounded only its top corners and the bottom only its bottom corners. You can't expect the children views to have rounded corners just because the parent view has rounded corners.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the Top textview to have rounded only its top corners and the bottom only its bottom corners. By making the parent view rounded corner, I was hopping it would clip the corners of the children. I did it btw. I added the answer why it didn't seem to work

Comment: Then all you had to do is set top margin 0dp for the top TextView and bottom margin 0dp for the bottom TextView.

Comment: No setting of 0 margin necessary. What I provided above works apparently but not on Android Studio design screen, only on device. I will accept the answer being the closest to "do nothing, it works as is"

Comment: If you don't set any margin it's the same as 0dp because the view is exactly at the edge. Anyway, since the problem is solved everything's fine.

Answer (score 5):

res/drawable/background.xml

```
<shape  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#00ffffff"/>
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
       android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"  
       android:topRightRadius="8dp"
       android:topLeftRadius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Such a simple answer, works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this layout. Hope this is the give you the expected results you want.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_margin="16dp">



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/que"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/tvque"
        android:textColor="#cbd3db" />
    </RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/layoutbg1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/des"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tvdes"
        android:textColor="#2c365a"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**layout_bg**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <solid android:color="#3e4874"/>
 <corners android:topLeftRadius="6dp" android:topRightRadius="6dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp"/>
<padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" 
         android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

**layout_bg1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#fff"/>
<corners android:topLeftRadius="0.1dp" android:topRightRadius="0.1dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp" android:bottomRightRadius="6dp"/>
<padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" 
         android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: That solves problem of rounded corners in this example but wouldn't solve it if you have many children. It does not make sense to do relative layout for ever child!. I will +1 though